# A semifield of characteristic zero may have a finite number of elements

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, semigroups-and-monoids, semirings

A commutative semiring $(S, +, \cdot, 0, 1)$ with unity is said to be a semifield if for all $a, b\in S$,  $a+b=0$ implies that $a=0$ and $b=0$, and $a.b=0$ implies that either $a=0$ or, $b=0$.

I found the following statement in a literature:

> "As in the case of fields of characteristic $0$, semifields of characteristic $0$ are also infinite".

I feel that the above statement is not true. Following is a counterexample:

It is noted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3632733/does-every-idempotent-semiring-has-characteristic-zero) that every idempotent semiring has characteristic $0$.
Now, the idempotent semiring $$(\lbrace 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5\rbrace, \max, \min, 0, 5)$$ is a semifield with  $5$ as unity. This semiring has characteristic $0$,  but the number of elements in it is finite. Hence the claim that a semifield of characteristic $0$ may have a finite  number of elements. Please so correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Could you define "characteristic"? The usual definition might have several natural extensions to semirings: (a) smallest $n$ such that $n1=0$ (where $nx$ $1+1+1\dots$ $n$ times); (b) smallest $n$ such that $n1=(2n)1$. Also in https://arxiv.org/abs/1709.06923, semifields are assumed to have $(S-\{0\},\cdot)$ a group, which is not satisfied by your example.

Comment: @YCor I am considering the definition of characteristic as in the link provided. And also, the semifield i am considering here doesn't have multiplicative inverse.

Comment: So, your definition of characteristic (in your link, which is a MathSE question of yours) is equivalent to the smallest $n$ such that $n1=0$, or $0$ if no such $n$ exists. But would you provide a reference to the "statement you found in the literature"? Have you checked you're using the same definition? By the way in your example $5$ could be replaced by any number $\ge 1$, and with $5$ replaced by $1$ (namely $(\{0,1\},\max,\min,0,1)$ you even get a group removing $1$.

Comment: @YCor this is the literature i am referring to                                                  https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://fs.unm.edu/Vasantha-Book3.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwi3_9yexPnoAhXYT30KHZNvCHQQFjAAegQIARAB&usg=AOvVaw2D5TkuTC0TydJwn6np5-ZA          Also, please see page numbers: 30, 38, 53, 54.

Comment: Well Remark 1 p55 (referred in your post as "statement you found in the literature) is false and you gave an obvious counterexample (as I said, changing $5$ to $1$ is enough). I'm afraid the title of the linked monograph and its publisher house don't look very serious.

Comment: @YCor yes it seems to have been an inadvertent.

Comment: For this reason I'd rather suggest to define the characteristic as the pair $(k_1,k_2)$, where $k_1$ is the smallest positive $k$ such that there exists $n\ge 0$ with $n1=(n+k)1$, and $k_2$ is the smallest nonnegative number $n$ for which this holds with for $k=k_1$, and characteristic zero (or $(0,0)$ when $k_1$ doesn't exist. So your example has characteristic $(1,5)$. Characteristic zero in your sense means that the characteristic is not of the form $(k,0)$ with $k\ge 1$. The characteristic (as I propose) precisely describes the structure of the monogenous additive monoid generated by $1$.

Comment: @YCor Such definition might be interesting. Would please give more elaboration as to how the example in the question has characteristic $(1, 5)$?

Comment: Say $k_1$ is the main characteristic. The main characteristic is $1$ since $(m+1).1_K=m1_K$ for $m=5$. The smallest $m$ for which this holds is indeed $m=5$, so $k_2$ is $5$.

Comment: @YCor Ok. Do you see any relevance of this proposed characteristic being and ordered pair with that of edges of a graph in the graph theory?